# python - multiprocessing is slower than sequential

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

this is my first multiprocessing implementation, i have executed my code in sequential approach and it took me a minute to process around 30seconds to process 20 records. But i created a dictionary with each key having a set of records, and tried to apply the function using pool.map for every key. Now it is taking more than 2 minute to process though i am assigining each core for each process. Could someone help me to optimize this.

```
def f(values):
    data1 = itertools.combinations(values,2)
    tuple_attr =('Age', 'Workclass', 'Fnlwgt', 'Education', 'Education-num', 'marital-status', 'Occupation', 'Relationship', 'Race', 'Sex', 'Capital-gain', 'Capital-loss', 'Hours-per-week', 'Native country', 'Probability', 'Id')
    new = ((tuple_attr[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]) for pair in data1)
    skt = set(frozenset(temp) for temp in new)
    newset = set(s for s in skt if not any(p < s for p in skt))

    empty = frozenset(" ")
    tr_x = set(frozenset(i) for i in empty)
    tr = set(frozenset(i) for i in empty)
    for e in newset:
        tr.clear()
        tr = tr.union(tr_x)
        tr_x.clear()
        for x in tr:
            for a in e:
                if x == empty:
                    tmp = frozenset(frozenset([a]))
                    tr_x = tr_x.union([tmp])
                else : 
                    tmp = frozenset(frozenset([a]).union(x))
                    tr_x = tr_x.union([tmp])
        tr.clear()
        tr = tr.union(tr_x)
        tr = set(l for l in tr if not any(m < l for m in tr))

    return tr

def main():
    p = Pool(len(data)) #number of processes = number of CPUs
    keys, values= zip(*data.items()) #ordered keys and values
    processed_values= p.map( f, values )
    result= dict( zip(keys, processed_values ) ) 
    p.close() # no more tasks
    p.join()  # wrap up current tasks
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import csv
    dicchunk = {*****} #my dictionary
    main()
```

Comment: Try on a larger dataset? It takes quite a bit of work before multiple threads/processes become worth the overhead of context switching, forking etc.

Comment: That's one messy code, you really should work on your variable names.
And what @Corey said when I was typing my comment - larger data set. But not too much as this will be quite expensive on memory.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set?

Comment: @Corey with the time this is taking I doubt spawning overheads are relevant.

Comment: `p = Pool(len(data)) #number of processes = number of CPUs` simply didn't get it. Is `len(data)` your number of CPUs?

Comment: ok. This is my dictionary - http://dpaste.com/3DHBY9J --> sample dataset which i am trying to use.

Comment: @starrify yes. number of keys in the dictionary is my number of CPUs. That does not matter since i am using in cluster with more number of CPUs

Comment: @Puciek Yes. Sure. I will correct it eventually.. :)

Comment: @Jeeva Have you verified you get the right answer with both the multiprocessing and non-multiprocessing versions? I ask because in my tests processing certain sublists is just really slow. I don't think `multiprocessing` has anything to do with it.

Comment: I havent checked them actually, let me see now.

Comment: Oops. I checked it and you are right. It is taking time for certain sublists alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test program to run this once with `multiprocessing`, and once without:

```
def main(data):
    p = Pool(len(data)) #number of processes = number of CPUs
    keys, values= zip(*data.items()) #ordered keys and values
    start = time.time()
    processed_values= p.map( f, values )
    result= dict( zip(keys, processed_values ) ) 
    print("multi: {}".format(time.time() - start))
    p.close() # no more tasks
    p.join()  # wrap up current tasks

    start = time.time()
    processed_values = map(f, values)
    result2 = dict( zip(keys, processed_values ) ) 
    print("non-multi: {}".format(time.time() - start))
    assert(result == result2)
```

Here's the output:

```
multi: 191.249588966
non-multi: 225.774535179
```

`multiprocessing` is faster, but not by as much as you might expect. The reason for that is some of the sub-lists take *much* (several minutes) longer to finish than others. You'll never be faster than however long it takes to process the largest sub-list.

I added some tracing to the worker function to demonstrate this. I saved the time at the start of the worker, and the print it out at the end. Here's the output:

```
<Process(PoolWorker-4, started daemon)> is done. Took 0.940237998962 seconds
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)> is done. Took 1.28068685532 seconds
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)> is done. Took 42.9250118732 seconds
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)> is done. Took 193.635578156 seconds
```

As you can see, the workers are doing very unequal amounts of work, so you're only saving about 44 seconds vs being sequential.

Comment: Great. I got it, the samething i am seeing in my computer. Is there a way to balance this? Is there a way to balance it in a way that the worker which completes faster takes the next available task? And anyother possibility to optimize my code, because i dont know why takes long only for certain sub-lists. This is just 20 records, i am going to handle 50k records next.. :(

Comment: If you end up passing more than `cpu_count()` items to `map`, then workers will grab the next item from the iterable as long as there are some left. Trying to balance the issue with uneven sub-lists is probably going to be tricky. You'd need to find a way to split up the work that `f` is doing so that you can parallelize pieces of it, then combine them together. I really don't understand what you're doing in that method well enough to tell you the best way to do that (or if its even feasible).

Comment: Ok. But i cant split up the work which i am doing inside the function, it should be done sequentially. Anyways, thanks